# How to create a layer that attaches to the top of a browser window while the user scrolls down with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been doing something I probably wasn't supposed to be doing. I have a site designed with wix hosting. They do not support css layers but when you use their free version they automatically insert an ad at the top of each page with their logo and a sign up now button. I rewrote their code and used their server side to display my logo and sign up now button at the top fixed in view even the the page was scrolled down. However they just changed something and now I again have no sign up now button for my site.

I have seen JavaScript which can create a button to generate a layer at a fixed location but how can I generate a layer onload using a JavaScript code that stays in view at the top of the page while the page is scrolled down. Wix supports  tags. 
Can this same code be modified to allow a fix header and footer with just a center section that scrolls?
My site can be seen [here](http://www.apc2go.com). If you want an idea of what the layout currently is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code.

```
<div id="sMenuR" style="background-color: red; width:50px; height:50px; "> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var NS = (document.layers) ? true : false;
        var IE = (document.all) ? true : false;

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#sMenuR').click(function() {
                jQuery("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop : 0
                }, 600);
                return false;
            });

            if (IE) {
                window.setInterval(function() {
                    var position = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    jQuery("#sMenuR").animate({ top : position + "px" }, 600);
                }, 1000);
            }else{
                window.setInterval(function(){
                    jQuery("#sMenuR").animate({top : jQuery(document).scrollTop()  + "px" }, 600); 
                },1000);
            }
        }

        );
    </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this script is only generating the div layer but is not fixing it to the browsers window. I would like to have a div that floats at either the top or bottom of the page always visible while the customer scrolls up and down on the page content. This script is staying at the very bottom of each page and is only visible when the user scrolls all the way down to the bottom of the page. Please see my site for reference at www.apc2go.com it is the black line at the bottom of each page.